# Change CSS property with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation

I have a form that submits via jquery ajax to itself. I want to change the error message "#error" display from "none" to "block" if there is an error.

```
<?php
 $username = "username";
 $password = "password";
 if ($_POST['username'] != $username || $_POST['password'] != $password) {
 /*need to make change here*/
 ?>
```

/* Log in form*/

/*target page after logged in*/
 
and the submit function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {          
        $("#MHLogin").validate({
            errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
                   return true;
                },

            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $("#processing").show();
                form.submit();
                return false;

           },
            rules: {
                    username: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: true
                    }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

In essence the log in form is first displayed, if you log in correctly it shows the content. if you hit submit with nothing in the fields, the text inputs receive the error class - that part works. But if you submit a blank or incorrect form, the form just clears. I tried echo'ing "Error" in the first part if it's incorrect then using a success handler based on the returned value - and changing the disply - but when i add echo "Error"; it just prints "Error" on the top of the page.

thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PHP code, set a variable like this:

```
<?php
$state = 'block';
?>
<html>
    <script>
        var state = "<?=$state?>";
    </script>
</html>
```

Basically, you output a PHP variable to your file, and then use a global javascript variable to hold the value of that variable. In your Jquery code, you'll be able to read this variable.

I use a more modularized version of this in my framework where my render engine is able to control which CSS or JS file to load. There's also a global javascript object generated by my script that holds all global data like base url, server time zone, sync data, and so forth that is to be reused in all client side scripts.

Hope this helps.

UPDATE:

Here's how it works:

```
// In your html file 
<script>var a = '<?=$state?>';</script> <-- set the global var here
<script src="js/bar.js"></script>       <-- include your scripts after the global one

--------------------------------------------------------

// In your bar.js file 
alert(a)  // should show the contents of $state stored in the global var a
```

Comment: @Ruben, ok so I set the variable state, after that I don't follow. Sorry just not that smart. Usually from a remote PHP script I would echo eithe "Error" or "success" then in the success function do something like "success: function(data){ if (data="error")...display the error msg...not making the connection with what you posted, pls advise.

Comment: Why post the form to itself instead of some sort of validation script?  Other than that, it looks like you know exactly what to do.  In the php code, print "error" or "success" and compare it to data in your ajax.  Update `#errors` appropriately.

Comment: @tandu, normally I do use a remote form. Situation dictates this be done like this, its a stupid log in form to view a PHP gallery, this is the only way I can get it to work.

Comment: Why don't you create a php page `validate_photo_gallery_login.php` whose only purpose is to print "error" or "success" based on post data?

Comment: @tandu - when I do it like I have done it, I can restrict access to only those that have logged in. if I have the gallery in a page behind it, I can't find a reliable way to restrict the access. I made the mistake of showing my boss how to spoof headers (detect http referrer) and cookies. Like I said situation dictates, this is where I'm at.

Comment: What does spoofing http headers have to do with anything?  In addition to that, why does that even preclude you from having a different script for validation?  All that script would do is check for validation.  Your main page would be the one with the login/to show the pictures on the page.

Comment: Updated answer to explain it in better terms (I hope)

Comment: @tandu - i asked the question I needed to ask. Too much backstory to go into, we used to check referrer to make sure people weren't directly accessing the pages from outside, then I showed him you can spoof a header.

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design, no problem. :)